# All I feel like this doing is kicking back with a good movie

Tags: grammar, syntax

I came across a sentence from [ESLPod](https://www.eslpod.com/), episode 6 of "A day in the life of Jeff", as below,

> After a busy week, *all I feel like this doing is kicking back with a
>   good movie.*

I guess I know the meaning of this whole sentence. It means "After a busy week, all I want to do is relax and watch a movie". I am not sure what it means by "this doing" here. Could someone explain what grammar it is?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that **this** is  not meant or supposed to be used there.

Comment: It's true that *kick back* can be used informally to mean "to relax", but the sentence sounds a bit too strange for me to think it's grammatical. However, this would be fine with me: *After a busy week, all I feel **like doing** is kicking back with a good movie.* (Note that I'm not a native speaker, and I can't say that I'm familiar with all dialects of English.)

Comment: @SamHarrington Er, it indeed exists in my material. I am wondering if"doing" is a noun here  "this" is to emphasize timing for example like "right now".

Comment: @DamkerngT. I also don't like "this" here:-( Maybe it is a very informal usage.

Comment: I don't know about "this doing", but you could use a possessive pronoun, like in *my doing*. Ex: "It was not *my doing*."

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the quotation contains a typographical error.

Comment: @user3169: Normally I'm fine with closing typo questions, but in cases where dedicated ESL material has an error, I'm not sure that's necessary. It seems much more likely that more learners would a) run across the problem, since it's *for* learners (especially as opposed to a specific printing of a famous book that happens to introduce an error not present in other printings) and b) be led astray by a seemingly authoritative source which is specifically trying to teach English.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Basically because 1. The immediate question has been answered. and 2. There is no significant educational reason to keep such a question archived for future use, as it is limited to one erroneous source. The accuracy of ESL materials would be a valid question, but that is not what was asked (and the source is not even in the question).

Comment: @user3169: Yes, but both of my points added up to the fact that the erroneous source is much more likely to be asked about in the future, so providing a proper answer for it is actually quite reasonable.

Comment: @NathanTuggy If the question and answer are up-voted, I don't think closing the question deletes it. It will still be here if other folks come across the same error. Actually it's only duplicates that aren't deleted: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/ Still I don't think it's that difficult to answer again if it comes up and if it comes up a lot, maybe we won't close it.

Comment: Just a tip: native speakers do not use *meet (met)* in this way. We would say *encountered* or *come across* or *read/heard*, but not *met*. Another example: you probably *encountered/came across* an error, not you *met* an error.

Comment: @AlanCarmack Thanks very much for pointing this out really! I like this community!

Comment: @Hua I meant that in the original text  don't think **this** is meant to be used there

Comment: @SamHarrington Yes, I got your idea. I thought it is used for some reasons before I asked it here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sentence in the source material is grammatically incorrect, and would sound wrong to a native speaker. The word 'this' shouldn't be there. If this quote is from a textbook, I would say it's a poorly written one.